# JavaScript fetch() can't catch error from 404

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch

I'm trying to handle a 404 in Chrome with this fetch() function.

```
function promiseBatchDomains(domainsToQuery) {
  var batchSize = domainsToQuery.length
  var currentDomain = 0
  var promises = domainsToQuery.map(domain => (
    fetch(`https://api-url-omitted/${domain}`)
      .then( res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          return res
        } else {
          throw Error(res.statusText)
        }
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        currentDomain += 1
        console.log(currentDomain + " of " + batchSize + ': ' + domain + ' data received.')
        percentCompletion = parseFloat(currentDomain / batchSize).toLocaleString(undefined,{style: 'percent'})
        $('#batchProgressBar').attr('aria-valuenow', percentCompletion).width(percentCompletion)
        return res
      })
      .then(res => ({ domain, res })
      .catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error))
  ))).filter(Boolean)

  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(results => makeCSV(results))
}
```

I need help understanding why the error I'm throwing in the if/else statement isn't being caught by the catch.

Based on the approaches outlined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), [here](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api), [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-fetch/), and [here](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/), I've tried this a couple of different ways: By throwing an error, as in my code above, and also by `Promise.reject()`. It hangs up either way, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something more fundamental.

In my console, I just see the raw 404, but not the console.log from my error, which I believe should fire if the catch was triggered. (When it's not a 404, the rest of this function works as expected.)

UPDATE: I've refactored the third `.then()` method with an if statement like this:

```
.then(res => {
        currentDomain += 1
        if (domain) {
          console.log(currentDomain + " of " + batchSize + ': ' + domain + ' data received.')
          percentCompletion = parseFloat(currentDomain / batchSize).toLocaleString(undefined,{style: 'percent'})
          $('#batchProgressBar').attr('aria-valuenow', percentCompletion).width(percentCompletion)
          return {domain, res}
        }
      })
```

Now the catch triggers. Shouldn't `throw Error()` cause it to skip all the `.then()` methods and go straight to the error?

Comment: I'm curious to know what will happen if you add a `catch` to `Promise.all(promises).then(...)`

Comment: @user3405291 I gave that a shot, but the function never gets that far because it hangs up on the uncaught 404s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I had a couple of issues here that I was able to resolve:

1. Needed to wrap expressions containing variables in if statements to prevent undefined values from hanging up the script.
2. Needed to move the `.filter(Boolean)` under the `Promise.all()`, like so: `Promise.all(promises).then(results => results.filter(Boolean)).then(results => makeCSV(results))`

The filter(Boolean) wasn't part of the problem stated in the original question, but it ended up causing undefined variables to be passed to subsequent functions. By filtering on Boolean this way, I avoided passing bad values downstream.